# How to properly manage the center of rotation of the view when painting in 3D editor?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, texture-painting

When in Texture Paint mode, and painting in the 3D editor, the center of rotation of the view is not anymore a fixed point (viewport center, selection center, 3D cursor) like it is in Object and Edit modes.

My understanding from experimentation is the CoR is close to the current cursor location.

For simple cases, like say... painting a donut :-) in the 3D view, it is useful to have a fixed CoR at the center of the object. But this seems not possible.

[image]

After rotation, the new faces to be painted are now located closer to the point of view, so a zoom-out and a translation are necessary to relocate the object at a better position.

This will repeat until done, or the death of the artist, whatever comes first ;-)

A workaround seems to relocate the CoR using Ctrl-LMB.

Is that right? What else needs to be known on this topic? What is the usual practice? (though the latter question may be a bit subjective.)

Comment: I have my settings to use rotate around selected, turntable, and I often use a shortcut I made for myself to utilize the align view to top of selected face. That shortcut enters and exits edit mode to use the option that is available there for face selection, and I often use it with face selection masking.